# Microsoft Fakes doesn't generate fakes assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I'm currently trying to unit test custom libraries by using Microsoft Fakes in VS 2015 Enterprise. I followed various guides like [this](https://adamprescott.net/2012/08/21/a-shim-ple-tutorial-with-microsoft-fakes/) or [this](http://jdav.is/2015/11/04/two-ways-to-mock-system-web-httpcontext/) in order to get this up and running on my project, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

For reference, I published a custom test project on [GitHub](https://github.com/ginomessmer/unittest-fakes-liftoff).

Each time I try to rebuild my project it says it successfully built all assemblies, but my fakes assembly doesn't show up in VS although it exists in my file directory. Here's the current configuration:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="UnitTestFakesLiftoff.Core"/>
</Fakes>
```

Comment: This happens sometimes when the initial addition of the fakes fails because generation couldn't complete (e.g. sometimes for mscorlib). then you need to manually add reference to the generated file.

Comment: @zaitsman Works like a charm, thanks!